# Dot vs arrow notation in Objective-C for non structs

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I've seen examples of arrow notation used for structs. In one tutorial, I saw this syntax in a view controller implementation file:

```
self->webView.canGoBack) backButton.enabled = YES;
```

I have no idea why they did not use dot notation. No explanation was given. I tried this in a simple project that has a button and text field. Below is what I put in the button press method:

```
//header file

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myInputField;

//implementation file

self.myInputField.text = @"another test";
//self->_myInputField.text = @"text field test";
```

Either line of code works without issue. So why use one of the above lines over the other?

Also, notice that the arrow notation produces `_myInputField.text`. What is the significance of the underscore?

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C, objects are also c structs. If you're new to the language, that knowledge will get you in more trouble than it will help. But it helps explain what you're seeing.

An Objective-C property is a helpful construct that creates an ivar in the object (a new field in the class's struct) that defaults to the property name prefixed by an underscore. A property will also create getter and setter methods, e.g. `- (UITextFeild *)myInputField` and `- (void)setMyInfputField`.

Dot notation is Objective-C syntactic sugar that calls the Objective-C setter and getter methods. The `->` arrow notation is C syntax that will dereference the object's pointer and access the struct field for the object's ivar.

It is important to understand that the dot syntax is actually generating calls to these methods, so you don't try and override those methods and inadvertently include calls to themselves.

The default implementation of a generated method like `- (UITextFeild *)myInputField` looks something like this

`- (UITextFeild *)myInputField {
    return self->_myInputField;
}`

But Objective-C has yet another syntactic helper allowing you to access `_myInputField` without writing out `self->`. So the following implementation is identical.

`- (UITextFeild *)myInputField {
    return _myInputField;
}`

There are some good reasons for using direct ivar access -- the biggest reasons being implementation of custom setters and getters, performance, and careful control over KVO language features. But in modern Objective-C it should be avoided unless you really know what you're doing.

If you want to learn more, read [Apple's documentation on Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW2)

Answer (score 1):

```
self.myInputField.text = @"another test";
```

That code calls the `myInputField` getter *method*. There can be good reason for doing this, so it is usually safest.

```
self->_myInputField.text = @"text field test";
```

That code directly accesses the `_myInputField` *instance variable*.

The `myInputField` getter method in this case *also* accesses the `_myInputField` instance variable, which is why the two calls seem to do the same thing. But that is just an implementation detail; it is perfectly possible for a getter method to access a differently named instance variable, to perform other actions (side effects), or to access no instance variable at all.

Comment: And see, for my complete discussion: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_properties_2